# Decide whether the map $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_{10}$ given by $f(n)=[n]$ is injective or surjective. Prove both.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

Decide whether the map $f:\mathbb Z\to\mathbb Z_{10}$ given by $f(n)=[n]$ is injective or surjective. Prove both.

Any help would be appreciated.

P.S. what does exactly $\mathbb Z_{10}$ mean? suddenly my professor started using this notation and I had a no idea.

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_arithmetic

Comment: clearly it's not injective due to cardinality issues

Comment: You have little chance of proving a statement that you do not understand! I think that in a situation like this you should first ask "What does $\mathbb{Z}_{10}$ mean?" as a separate question, NOT AS AN AFTERTHOUGHT.  Very often, you can then solve the problem on your own. If you can't, you can ask another question: "Is this map injective or surjective?"

Comment: If your professor uses notation that isn't familiar to you, you should ask them about its meaning.

Comment: Note: f (10k + n) = [n].  So what does injective mean?  Also note: for any 0 $\le $ n < 10 that f (n)=[n].  So what does surjective mean?

Answer (score 1):

$\mathbb Z_{10}$ is the integers modulo $10$. To construct $\mathbb Z_{10}$, start with the integers $\mathbb Z$, and define a relation on them by $a\,R\,b$ if $a-b$ is a multiple of $10$. This relation turns out to be an equivalence relation, and it has exactly ten equivalence classes: $[0],\,[1],\,[2],\,...,[9].$ We can do arithmetic in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ like this: $[a]+[b]=[a+b]$, and $[a]\times[b]=[a\times b]$. For example, $[6]+[8]=[14]=[4]$ and $[6]\times[8]=[48]=[8]$. Note that multiplication has some different properties in $\mathbb Z_{10}$ than in $\mathbb Z$. For example, if $a$ and $b$ are integers, then if $ab=0$, then either $a$ or $b$ are zero. But if $a=2$ and $b=5$, then $[a]\times [b]=[2]\times [5]=[10]=[0]$.So we can multiply nonzero things and get zero.

Now to answer your question. The map $f$ takes the integer $n$ to its equivalence class. It is not injective. Can you think of two integers that have the same equivalence class modulo $10$? The function $f$ is surjective. This is not hard to see. For each $[a]$, what integer maps to $[a]$ under $f$?

Answer (score 0):

It is not injective because $f(1) = f(11) = 1$.

It is surjective because for any $x \in \mathbb{Z}_{10}$, $f(x) = x$.